# Memory Leaks with TList<T>.Pack

Tags: delphi, generics, tlist

Consider a simple class TMyObject that contains an array[0..9] of string (Description) and some other properties (omitted for this example).  At a certain point, I want to remove all "empty" objects (i.e. where all 10 string are empty) from FMyList (TList<TMyObject>).  For this purpose I am using the Pack method with the IsEmpty function:

```
FMyList.Pack(
  function(const MyObject1, MyObject2: TMyObject): boolean
  var
    ii: Integer;
  begin
    result := true;
    for ii := 0 to 9 do
      if (MyObject1.Description[ii] <> '') then
      begin
        result := false;
        break;
      end;
  end);
```

Initially I (wrongfully) assumed Pack would also free (release) the objects.  This is not the case, so the above code causes memory leaks, leaving the removed TMyObjects "dangling".

Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit sparse on Pack.  How to correctly use this method and ensure that after a Pack, not only are the objects removed from the TList but also correctly freed?

Comment: The "obvious" solution would be to use a `TObjectList<T>` (with `OwnsObjects = True`)  instead of a `TList<T>`, but apparently the `Pack` method doesn't support this distinction.

Answer (score 4):

`Pack` is specifically to remove *empty* items from the list with empty being related to the data type. That is why it does not trigger any OnChange event as it technically does not remove items but just empty slots in the backing array.

The overload with `IsEmpty` func is not meant for "remove all items from the list where this and that applies".

That being said for your task using `Pack` is not the solution. You will have to use a backwards loop and `Delete`. When using a `TObjectList<T>` with `OwnsObjects = True` it will automatically destroy the object. Otherwise you need to do that yourself.

Edit: Just to mention this for completeness sake - but I advise against doing this: you can still `.Free` the item inside the `IsEmpty` func you provide when you return `True`. But imho that code is kinda smelly.

Comment: Just to elaborate further, the non-generic `TList` holds only pointers, so it's `Pack()` simply removes `nil` pointers. But the generic `TList<T>` may or may not hold pointers (in this case, it does), so the version of `Pack()` being used wants the user to define what "invalid" items look like so they can be removed as-is. Which is what the OP's anonymous procedure attempts to do, but removing valid allocated objects as "invalid" is wrong since `TList<T>` won't `Free` them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Generic `TList<T>` has nothing to do with non-generic one from System.Classes.pas despite both having a `Pack` method. The parameterless Pack method from `TList<T>` also removes nil pointers when T is a class type as it checks against `Default(T)`.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said "*the version of `Pack()` being used*", I just did not have time to mention the parameter-less `Pack()` when I posted that.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I have to disagree when you state "_The overload with IsEmpty func is not meant for "remove all items from the list where this and that applies"._ because this is literally what the documentation implies [HERE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Pack).  This all works as expected except that if the TList contains objects, they are not released, just removed.  To do this in the IsEmpty function is indeed "ugly" (or "smelly" if you like) but that is the last point where you still have a handle on the object.

Comment: Interesting question is how you would use Pack on a TList<Integer>.  What defines an "empty" Integer? E.g, with the IsEmpty function, you could define (e.g.) to remove all Integers that are -1.

Comment: The point is that obviously due to its implementation emptiness on objects does not include an assigned object with some property set to some "empty" value. If you disagree then open an issue about this at quality portal and hope for the best.